# Como evitar duplicação de controllers/responsabilidade em aplicações modernas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Nos dias de hoje, a comunicação entre aplicações, mobile e/ou outros dispositivos está cada vez maior.

O .net fornece o `Asp.net MVC` e `Asp.net WebAPI` (até a data de hoje, versão estável).

Comumente o `Asp.net MVC` retorna `Views`, apesar do `WebApi` também retornar não é o correto. A maneira mais correta de usar uma API seria apenas dados (`json`)

Então, como evitar a duplicação de `Controllers` para casos em que eu precise também fazer a comunicação com `mobile` e `aplicação web`? Sabendo que em ambos terá os métodos `CRUD(Create/Read/Update/Delete)` implementados

Sei que `Single Page Application(SPA)` é uma opção para reaproveitar o mesmo Controller Api, mas e caso não estamos usando `SPA` ?

Answer (score 1):

Para o caso do ASP.NET MVC5, em que é impossível fazer o mesmo *Controller* servir mais de um tipo de formato de informação, a abordagem mais adequada é escrever uma camada intermediária que processe a requisição toda, criando dois grupos de *Controllers*, sendo um para requisições que devolvam HTML e outro que devolva requisições em JSON, cada uma com sua tabela de rotas.

Portanto, para o caso do MVC5, a duplicação de *Controllers* não é evitável.

Para o caso do ASP.NET MVC6, não há necessidade desta separação porque o *Controller* é o mesmo para qualquer formato de informação. Até a data desta resposta, a implementação já é unificada, mas até então não encontrei uma forma simples de a aplicação identificar o que servidor que não seja com base na configuração de rotas.

Comment: Obrigado Cigano :D